# TypeScript Yup | Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, schema, formik, yup

I am trying to create my ValidationSchemas using TS, React in order to use them in a Formik form.

I have multiple validation schemas I need to comply with in my module, so I thought of creating an enum, in order to easily reuse them.

**IN A TS File:**

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

export const ValidationSchema {
  AddUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string('Provide a username').required('Username is required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Provide a valid email address'),
    password: Yup.string('Provide a password').required('Password is required'),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string('Provide your password again')
      .required('Password confirmation is required')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match'),
    group: Yup.string('Please select a group').required('Group is required')
  }),
  EditUserSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string('Provide a username').required('Username is required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Provide a valid email address'),
    group: Yup.string('Please select a group').required('Group is required')
  }),
  EditPasswordSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    password: Yup.string('Provide a password').required('Password is required'),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string('Provide your password again')
      .required('Password confirmation is required')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match'),
  }),
}
```

But I get errors in every Yup.String, that say:

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
const string: Yup.StringSchemaConstructor
() => Yup.StringSchema
```

I am trying to find reference to the Yup types, but no luck. What is the problem here. I need to pass an argument to Yup, and it says, that is expected 0. Doesn't make sense to me. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error message and the types for for yup [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/yup/index.d.ts), it seems the problem is the calls you're making like this: `Yup.string('Please select a group')`. It seems the `StringSchemaConstructor` interface doesn't define a property which takes a `string`.

Comment: So, the answer is I cannot use it with TS? Or?? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can use it with TS, but I'm not sure the yup API supports `Yup.string('Please select a group')`. https://github.com/jquense/yup#string

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Typescript compatibility. use `Yup.string()` . for more details vistit: [Yup Typescript](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/docs/typescript.md)